# Character Map in linux?

Tags: windows, linux, software-rec

Windows has a `character map` utility. Is there one in Linux? I'm using KDE; but I'm sure that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check out this summary: http://fsymbols.com/character-maps/linux/

It lists different utilities for GNOME, KDE or other environments:

- gucharmap, is the GNOME Character Map, based on the Unicode Character Database
- Ubuntu Character Map
- KCharSelect, an advanced character map tool in KDE
- Java Character Map is a Java charmap program you can download. It works on any platform, where Java environment is installed.

Answer (score 7):

KCharSelect, a character map that lets you choose virtually any possible character and preview them in any font on your system, is available for KDE desktops.

You can open it by going to Applications > Utilities > Character Selector.

If you find it's not installed, then open your Linux package manager and search for the `kcharselect` package.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [Gnome character map](https://live.gnome.org/Gucharmap). It works fine on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

I use character maps heavily and decides to make one which you access from anywhere using [a web interface](http://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/) and requires no installation.

**Features**

- Select your own font file
- Provides font and character information
- Character copy-able
- Supports TTF/OTF
- Supports Icon fonts
- Smooth interface
- No installation necessary
- No server upload necessary

**Screenshot**

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Great app, however it doesn't quite work on Firefox 40.0.3 (on my FreeBSD). Can't change the character set. Works great in Chrome.