# Typing alt codes on keyboard without numeric pad

Tags: linux, windows, special-characters, symbols, numpad

I bought this keyboard without a numeric pad but as I found out I'm not able to use alt codes with it to type symbols such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>30</kbd> makes ▲ or ■ and so on

Is there a trick how to type alt codes on a keyboard without a num pad? I'm using both Windows and Linux so would be cool if it was OS independent.

[image: keyboard]

Answer (score 2):

There are many cross-platform methods that you can use:

- In most word processing apps like MS Word, Wordpad, Libre Office... you can just enter the Unicode hex value then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

  For example to type ▲ (U+25B2) you can type `U+25B2` or `25B2` then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Use PowerShell which is available for both [Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7.1) and [Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1). For example to get the above black triangle you have many ways like

  ```powershell
  Set-Clipboard "`u{25B2}" # or
  scb "`u{25B2}"           # or
  "`u{25B2}" | scb         # or
  [char]0x25B2 | Set-Clipboard
  ```

  After that paste to wherever you want
- Use the browser. You can use the JavaScript `copy` function to copy the desired characters to clipboard. It works in most modern browsers like Firefox, Chrome/Chromium (including Chromium Edge). For example to type ■ (U+25A0) use either of these

  ```js
  copy("\u25A0")   // only applicable for characters inside the BMP (⩽ U+FFFF)
  copy("\u{25A0}") // applicable for all characters (U+0000 to U+10FFFF)
  copy(String.fromCodePoint(0x25A0))
  ```
- Use the emoji panel. This works for emojis and many common symbols but not for all, but it's extremely simple, quick and easy to use. There's no need to remember the Unicode code points anymore

  - In Windows use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>. (period)</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>; (semicolon)</kbd>

    [image: Windows emoji panel]

    See [How do I bring up the emoji IME on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1255287/241386)
  - In Ubuntu and many other Linux distros [you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to open it](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/use-emoji-linux-ubuntu-apps)

    [image: Ubuntu emoji picker]

    Depending on your setting, your distro and your desktop environment you may need to install some additional packages or use another shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. See

    - [How to insert an emoji into a text in Ubuntu 18.04 and later?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1045915/253474)
    - [What happened to the emoji picker from Linux Mint 19?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/579933/44425)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:

- Use On Screen Keyboard (enter OSK in Start/Run).
- Use Numpad Emulator which will take less space on screen.
- Use Character Map (enter *charmap* in Start/Run).

For linux:

- Character Map for linux  ([Character Map in linux?](https://superuser.com/q/450058/822976))

There may be alternatives available for OSK and Numpad emulator for linux too. You can search for them.